# How to call an external service with jbpm

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jbpm, bpmn

I am using jbpm 7.26 to create a process that can call an external REST API and simply display the result.

Unfortunately, there is absolutely no tutorial on the subject, I'm trying to call an URL like:

```
GET https://api.darksky.net/forecast/secretkey/37.8267,-122.4233
```

the two last numbers being the weather longitude and latitude I want to get

I have tried to create a REST task in the business process.
I've set the URL I showed before as a parameter and I tried to set a String as an output but not sure it works tho.

An error appears when I deploy the project and arrive on this task in a process:
Unable to complete your request. The following exception occurred: "Unable to create response: [Meteo.GetMeteo:29 - GetMeteoRestService:5] -- Could not find work item handler for Rest".

I've also tried to create a Service task but I have no idea on how to fill the information to call the REST service

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to get the JSON return of the URL request, only that for the moment.

Hope I'm clear enough and thank you by advance for your help :)

Comment: after installing the WorkItem, did you succeeded to get your response into ResultatMeteo type (localite variable)? because in my case I can only get it as a String variable, I can not convert it into a custom Object. I hope it was clear. Merci.

Comment: The retrieved response is a json/string/other classic format. You can add java code when receiving it, then do whatever you wanna do with it. You can create a converter which converts json to the object you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you didn't install Work Item Handler. You can install it in Project settings
[image]